# how to manipulate resultset

Tags: java, resultset

i am using java and postgres in my application. 
i am fetching data from the data base and use my logic against the data that is stored in the result set . after that i want to manipulate the second field of the result set through the statement

```
 rs.updateString(2,s);
```

is my approch of manipulating the result set is correct. as i am not able to change the data that is stored in the result set through the above statement and while executing the above statement i am getting the exception. please help ...

after using the advice i have modified the program and my code is

```
    Connection con = getNonTConnection();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
    String strSQL = "Query for fetching two fields from database";
    pstmt=con.prepareStatement(strSQL,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    pstmt.setString(1, locationID);
    log.debug(pstmt);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next())
    {
        piscode = rs.getString("pis_code").trim();
        password = rs.getString("pis_passwd").trim(); 
        passwdMatched = checkPassword(piscode,password); // return true or false 
        if(passwdMatched)
            s="true";
        else 
            s="false";
        rs.updateString(2,s);// this statement still result in error 
     }
```

the list of errors i got

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name location not found.
13602ms [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG: 2014-May-09 @ 12:35:58,327 (JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:createParser:1333)
Using SAX parser factory class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory
at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.findColumn(AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.java:673)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.isUpdateable(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1351)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.updateValue(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1517)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.updateString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1122)
```

in the code after the modification of

```
 rs.updateRow();
```

i still got the error

```
     org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name location not found.
at org.postgresql.jdbc1.AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.findColumn(AbstractJdbc1ResultSet.java:673)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.isUpdateable(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1351)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.updateValue(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1517)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.updateString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1122)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.updateString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1211)
```

Comment: what exception exactly are you getting? please add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

You make sure to create the `PreparedStatement` allowing updatable `ResultSet`s. This will work if you call [`Connection#prepareStatement(String sql, int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-int-int-) and passing:

- `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` as `resultSetType` parameter.
- `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` as `resultSetConcurrency` parameter.

Code example:

```
Connection con = ...
String sql = "SELECT ...";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
    sql,
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    //...
    String s = ...;
    //...
    rs.updateString(2,s);
    //important!
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

More info:

- [JDBC Basics. Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_update)

Note that this may fail if your JDBC driver doesn't support these values for the `ResultSet`, though.

Comment: you could also note that only scrolled ResultSets are updatable. +1

Comment: @akhilless added the info.

Comment: i followed you advice but my program still not working the code i write is   String strSQL = "Query";
pstmt.setString(1, locationID);
pstmt =con.prepareStatement(strSQL,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); log.debug(pstmt);rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
   while (rs.next()) {
 piscode = rs.getString("pis_code").trim();
 password = rs.getString("pis_passwd"); 
 pis.add(piscode);
 pwd.add(password);passwdMatched = checkPassword(piscode,password);
if(passwdMatched)
s="true";
else 
s="false";
rs.updateString(2,s);

Comment: @user3610984 update your code in your question, do not put it in comments.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please help

Comment: @user3610984 have you read the last part at the bottom of my answer? *this may fail if your JDBC driver doesn't support these values for the `ResultSet`*. If that's your problem, then you will need to use another `PreparedStatement` to update the current row.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i don't know that if this is the driver problem please let me know how to check that this is the issue that is related to the driver and how to correct that

Comment: @user3610984 what's the name of the postgre jar you're using?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza   pg.jar

Comment: how can i manipulate the result set through the 'preparedStatement'.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please help in getting the solution and is the problem can be solved through the creating the another prepared statements that can be used in the result set manipulation or do i need to upgrade the JDBC driver for that

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i have made the changes that you have mention but my method rs.updateString(2,s); still has the error